# Probability - a group of sellers

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

There is a group of 10 medicine sellers in a neighborhood with 80 houses. Each seller is responsible for 8 different houses. The probability to sell medicine to a specific house is 0.8. The seller is excellent if he manages to sell to at least 7 houses. A group is excellent if at least $80$% of the sellers are excellent. What is the probability that in an organization consists of 20 groups of sellers, exactly 2 groups are excellent?

So, I understood it's a Binomial distribution. I think you need to check the probability to be excellent, $P(X=7) + P(X=8)$, from there I can't understand how to distinguish from that the $80%$ of sellers that are excellent. any direction?

Comment: It's like Russian dolls of probabilities. You need to first calculate the probability that a group is excellent. Then you can treat a group as a random variable and give it 20 trials, and calculate what's the probability that 2 of those trials are successful...

Comment: Did you mean 8 instead of 80?

Comment: @mrbronstedlowry edited it's 80%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that a given individual is excellent is given by ...

$$p_1 = \binom 87 (0.8)^7 (0.2)^1 +\binom 88 (0.8)^8 (0.2)^0 \sim 0.503 $$

The probability that a group is excellent is given by ...
$$p_2 = \binom {10}8p_1^8 q_1^2 +  \binom {10}9p_1^9 q_1^1 +  \binom {10}{10}p_1^{10} q_1^0  \sim 0.057$$

Finally, the probability that exactly 2 out of 20 groups are excellent is ...
$$P=\binom{20}2 (p_2)^2(q_2)^{18} \sim 0.215 $$

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer! it's making sense now. I have another question following up, In an organization of 20 groups of sellers, How much on average will be excellent? Do I just put it in the formula np from the binomical distribution? X~Bin (0.057, 20)

Comment: Yes - that is the correct way to calculate the expected number of excellent groups $np=1.14$